# How to list devices on local network

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to list connected devices on local network like this.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPFM9.png)

I tried to use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/ping_discover_network_forked) package but i couldn't find the solution. The other solutions i find is so old and no work anymore.

What roadmap should I follow for this?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually two approaches to network surveys.

1. Use [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) to determine what services are being published on the local network.  There are usually mDNS clients available on most platforms.  In addition to deciding if there's a host, advertisements by mDNS will also help determine the type of device and the services offered (web servers, printing, other kinds of services).
2. Listen for, and parse network [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) traffic.  This works well for most devices which use ARP to resolve IP addresses on the local network to MAC addresses as part of the TCP/IP protocol.  This will get you most of the devices on the network by IP address and MAC address.  This doesn't give you specifics like mDNS does, but can tell you who the manufacturer of the devices is, by interpreting the manufacturer code portion of the MAC.
3. Survey the network by connecting to all IP addresses in sequence.  This is slowest, but most complete.  By attempting to use [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) to ping each device, you can see if there's a device even if it hasn't been advertised using the ARP protocol, or advertising services via mDNS.  This won't tell you who the manufacturer is, or what the services the device allows, but it does tell you if the IP address has a device (mostly).

And, you can always combine these techniques to get more detailed information built up over time.

I have no idea if there are existing prepackaged solutions in flutter for any of this, but I suspect that somewhere there are a few examples with varying levels of maturity.